# How to handle Twitter "Rate limit encountered ..." in R?

Tags: r, api, twitter

I'm totally new to this. I'm using the package "twitteR" on Rstudio to access Twitter rest APIs and pull data from Twitter data.

```
username <- "netflix"
user <- getUser(username) 
followers <- user$getFollowers() 
followers <- twListToDF(followers)
```

Then I got the following notification

> Rate limit encountered & retry limit reached - returning partial results

It's been over 15 minutes and I haven't got any results yet. so I modified the code to

```
followers <- user$getFollowers(150)
```

And get the result, but it's a dataframe full of numbers, what does this mean?

> 794705342974328832
>    39308631
>   807216507939880960
>   808263559599845376
>   2507888091
>   174977598
>   338081716
>   807803521810698240
>   2775999428
>   2570734208

---

I was wondering if something's wrong with my API keys and changed up the code to the following

`searchNF <- searchTwitter("#netflix bad OR suck OR terrible OR disaster OR :(", n=1500, since=as.character(Sys.Date()-3))
negativeTweets <- length(searchNF)
negativeSentiment <- negativeTweets/1500`

And get the following notice

> 1500 tweets were requested but the API can only return 52>  negativeTweets

Is this normal?

Comment: Are they the User Ids of the followers of 'netflix'? what is the output of `str(followers)` ?

Comment: For Twitter accounts with large followings, the results are sent in pages, and I believe that it takes one request per page. If Netflix has millions of followers, you are unlikely to get the full result set back in one go. It's not an easy fix, but it could be worth exploring the `getFollowers()` source code to see how pagination is dealt with, and see if you can use `Sys.sleep(6)` or some equivalent to spread out the requests.

Comment: It also looks like the function is only returning user IDs. There is a method called getFollowers() and getFollowerIDs(). The former will return whole objects, while the latter will return just the IDs.

Comment: @OliverFrost Thanks for explaining it! I actually used getFollowers() for my code, but it only returned the IDs instead of whole objects. Like you said it's not an easy fix to get the full result set back in one go. I'm thinking, instead of pulling data from the followers of 'netflix', can I perform the search of public tweets related to "netflix movies'? Would that be a easier approach? Would love to hear your insights on this, appreciate your time and efforts

Comment: edit your question with that output - the comments section is not really appropriate. Either way, you've got a `data.frame` of 17 columns, so the output you've put in your question for `followers` doesn't appear to be correct.

Comment: @SymbolixAU Gotcha, I'll try a different approach then. Meanwhile I changed up the code and try `searchTwitter` instead, but my API keys were only able to return 52 out of 1500 tweets.